# Trying to translate Genesis Sample Child Theme?

Tags: wordpress, translate, genesis

I'm using Genesis Sample Child Theme for my website. There is a line of code in function.php:

```
load_child_theme_textdomain( genesis_get_theme_handle(), get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
```

I know this mean .po and .mo file must upload to **wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/languages** but I try to upload it to different folder **wp-content/languages/themes** and name the .po and .mo file genesis-sample-vi and website still translate.
Any idea why it still working no matter the code above?

Comment: What did you expect to happen? The code will NOT look in the folder you mentioned but the languages subfolder of the theme for its translations. So, either change the code in functions.php (create a child theme for that!) or use the folder that is meant to be used.

Comment: I don't know why the code could find and load .po and .mo files in a different folder written in the code. As you say, the code look in the languages subfolder of the theme, but I uploaded .po and .mo files in a different folder (wp-content/languages/themes folder)

Comment: What is your problem here? Do your translation files work, although they are placed in a wrong directory? Or do they not work, because you placed them in the wrong directory?

Comment: It is translate files work although they are placed in a wrong directory. It's confusing